# Can customers share their code without expose it?

Tags: firmware, industrial

Sorry for the fuzzy headline as I am not sure how to present the problem I am facing in a short way, neither I am not a software engineer by myself and not sure if stack overflow is the right place to ask this.

The problem statements is as follow:
My company selling code A to others companies who wrap it resulting
with final firmware code B(A).

Code A may have issues, as an attempt to debug it we create code A', send it to the customer who build B(A') and share back with us to try on their hardware.
Note that customers only share the final image of B(A') and not the method to build it by ourselves.
This turnaround kind of flow is inefficient time wise.

Ideally customer would be able to supply a method to create B() in a secure way from their side.
I don't know if that possible or common issue in the industry.

I know it not a regular coding question but thanks for reading.

Comment: "secure" in what terms? Securely transfering to you? Securely in terms of no bugs in the code? Something else?

Comment: Customer may won't agree to share their code for us to be able to build the whole B() firmware.
I would say a secure why will be one that allow us to build it without the option to actual have their code.
This is just my assumption but they may more requirements.

Comment: In my opinion this can only be achieved by signing some NDA contract/legal document, not by some technology.